# Raspberry Pi dnsmasq performance

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq, adblock

I want to block ads in my whole network with dnsmasq running on a Raspberry Pi, connected via Ethernet to the router. Is there any reason to take a RPi3? Or is a RPi2 also sufficient for that task?

Shouldn't it be "just" dns queries that don't require a lot of bandwidth? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: https://www.pcworld.com/article/3200117/linux/how-to-use-raspberry-pi-as-dns-server-with-dnsmasq.html In the article he uses the RPi2

Comment: Would you say, that even a RPI1 would be sufficient (not that I have a spare one, but I am just curious)? Is there any reason that dnsmasq uses too much CPU / too much RAM for a RPI1?

Comment: No clue. I would think it would mostly be a memory requirement though

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Let's see if someone else has a comment to add. Sorry, but I cannot upvote any of your helpful comments!

Answer (score 0):

Default max DHCP requests is 1000 ( You can change it )
I use raspberry pi zero w / zero 2W for the same.
That is more than enough, I have close to 300 clients on network

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1201518)